# how to set maven source plugin output file encoding

Tags: java, maven, maven-source-plugin

using maven source plugin and upload source jar file successfully. while download maven sources from another computer and found source file chinese words messy.here is my build configuration in pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
    <configuration><encoding>UTF-8</encoding>UTF-8<charset></charset></configuration>
    <executions>
    <execution>
<id>attach-sources></id>
<phase>jar</phase>
<goals>
<goal>jar</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>` with `maven-resources-plugin 3.0.2` plugin, you can find code belop:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          ...
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

and if you are using Maven 3.x then you useadd below code

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>

    <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

and Maven 2.x, use below property:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    ...
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: how can i use maven resources plugin pack source file, i have tried this way but failed.

Comment: you need to put this `plugin` into `plugins` tag in `pom.xml`

Comment: The given solution for Maven 3 simply fails cause it wrong: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Answer (score 0):

The only solution which is valid is this one:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    ...
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

This solution is not related to Maven version (apart from that Maven 2 is end of life)..

This will set this property which is picked up by all apache maven plugins (maven-compiler-plugin,maven-resources-plugin etc.) which includes maven-sources-plugin. But you should use most recent [versions of the plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) and not such ancient version.